# jQuery image cross fade issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a 5 image slideshow that i'm trying to animate by fading between the images, rather than just switching between then.

My HTML is as follows,

```
<div id="slides">
    <ul class="pics">
        <li><img src="images1.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="images2.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="images3.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="images4.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="images5.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And my jQuery is as follows, I can get each images to fade away as it should, but the next image just appears, and doesn't fade in, have i missed something blatantly obvious?

```
var list2 = $('#slides .pics li');
list2.filter(':first').addClass('active').find('img').fadeIn(500);

setInterval(function() {
    if( list2.filter('.active').index() !== list2.length - 1 ) {
        list2.filter('.active').find('img').fadeOut(500, function(){
        list2.filter('.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
        });
        list2.filter('.active').find('img').fadeIn(500);
    }
    else {
        list2.filter('.active').find('img').fadeOut(500, function(){
        list2.removeClass('active').filter(':first').addClass('active');
        });
    }
}, 4000);
```

Comment: A [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be helpful...??

Comment: @Bhavik http://jsfiddle.net/YuxKx/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using .filter() that way. I'd do it more like this:

```
$('.pics img:first').show()
function doFade() {
    $('.pics li:first img').fadeOut(500, function () {
        $(this).parent().insertAfter($('.pics li:last'));
        $('.pics li:first img').fadeIn(500);
    })
}
setInterval(doFade, 4000)
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/FHWRT/)**

Comment: thank you for the responce, whilst that works perfectly i need to carry the `.active` class throughout, by removing and adding it to the parent <li> each time the image changes, thats what the .filter() was for.

Comment: You can still add the active class to whichever element you need (I'm assuming the visible image).